# semantic ui html works on pc but not from isp

Tags: semantic-ui

I am using semantic ui, and the html works fine on my pc.  When I upload it and run my site from the internet, it looks like the normal html is working, but sematic specific functionality is missing.  Is it not getting the semantic .css or something?  I'm a bit new to this, so if you could help me debug I would be be grateful.

I am using Semantic version 1.8.1.
My html is located relative to all the source files in the same way as the examples which come with the release in the /examples directory.  So I access the file relatively such as "../dist/semantic.css"

Here is the head section of the default.htm main html page.

```
<head>
<!-- Standard Meta -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

<!-- Site Properities -->
<title>Spin Boogie</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dist/semantic.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kitchensink.css">

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Used with Tab History !-->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.address/1.6/jquery.address.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/semantic.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Going back to bootstrap.  Semantic-ui needs to either work, or have some kind of support network.

Comment: If you could show us a screenshot of what the page looks like we may be able to see better. Be careful with Semantic UI versions as I am using an alpha version and it has quite a few problems such as certain icons don't work and styling variations. It also may be the relative paths that are not linking your css files.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with relative paths, but with the jquery.js file.  I went to the jquery download site (http://jquery.com/download/), got the latest file by selecting all text, and then saving as .js file.  Then when I include the jquery.js file relative to my html source instead of relative to the cloudflare.com it works great.

Comment: Thanks for help.  I am very happy with the things I can do on my webpage with Semantic-ui, and it works fine mixing the bootstrap functionality too.

Comment: That's great, May I ask how you are mixing Bootstrap functionality with Semantic-UI as I have wanted to do the same thing but there is then the clash of CSS

Comment: Basically I only do one segment at a time, either bootstrap or semantic. Ie bootstrap jumbotron, then semantic accordian, then bootstrap carousel, etc. I haven't tried mixing one with the other within the same div segment yet.  What clash are you getting?

Comment: Ok, I tried putting the boostrap carousel in a semantic <div class="ui segment"> and it works fine.  It actually looks better that way so I'll keep it like that!

Comment: So say if you use the Bootstrap navbar instead of the Semantic one, will it appear fine? surely there are some css name clashes in the core css files of both Bootstrap and Semantic?